# Como converter o número de horas em formato de data em r

Tags: r, data

> Tenho uma coluna neste formato e não consigo converte-la em formato de
>   data. Neste momento encontra-se em horas. Exemplo: 8,5 é na verdade
>   08:30:00 e por ai adiante... Alguma ideia de como o fazer? (ver
>   imagem)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
start_date <- as.POSIXct(data$START, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H")
data <- mutate(data, START=start_date)

end_date <- as.POSIXct(data$END, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H")
data <- mutate(data, END=end_date)
```

> Ao escrever o código nesse formato o que acontece é que ele "ignora"
>   as meias horas, ou seja, por exemplo, na primeira linha em vez de
>   colocar 08:30:00 coloca 08:00:00.

Comment: Poste uma amostra dos seus dados como texto (por exemplo, usando `dput` - consulte o tópico sobre exemplos mínimos reproduzíveis na ajuda do site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A seguinte função converte as datas com horas em números com decimais em datas com horas no formato `HH:MM:SS`.

```
dec2hour <- function(x){
  d <- sub("(^.*) .*$", "\\1", x)
  h <- sub("^.* ", "", x)
  h <- as.numeric(h)
  m <- h - floor(h)
  h <- floor(h)
  m <- m*60
  s <- m - floor(m)
  m <- floor(m)
  s <- s*60
  y <- paste(h, m, s, sep = ":")
  y <- as.POSIXct(paste(d, y))
  y
}

x <- c("2013-09-02 8.5", "2013-09-02 10", "2013-09-02 11.5", "2013-09-02 3.508333")
dec2hour(x)
#[1] "2013-09-02 08:30:00 WEST" "2013-09-02 10:00:00 WEST"
#[3] "2013-09-02 11:30:00 WEST" "2013-09-02 03:30:29 WEST"
```

Nota: `"WEST"` deve-se ao meu fuso horário.

```
Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
#[1] "pt_PT.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 2):

Se tem apenas horas inteiras ou meias horas, pode usar `gsub` para substir `.5` para `:30` antes de converter para POSIX. Escreva como uma função para evitar repetição de código quando for aplicar ao data.frame.

```
exemplo <- c('2013-09-02 8.5', '2013-09-02 9', '2013-09-02 10.5')

ajustaData <- function(x) {
  y <- paste0(x, ':00')
  y <- gsub('.5:00$', ':30', y)
  as.POSIXct(y, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
}

> ajustaData(exemplo)
[1] "2013-09-02 08:30:00 -03" "2013-09-02 09:00:00 -03" "2013-09-02 10:30:00 -03"
```

Answer (score 1):

Para transformar hora decimal em hora, basta manter a quantidade de hora e multiplicar os minutos por 60.

Exemplo: 1.50

Mantenho o 1 e pego os minutos como 0,50 e depois multiplico por 60... sendo assim ele se torna 30, agora é só concatenar 1||':'||30 e dar um parse para date.